# symfony 3.4.14 collectionType edit and delete issue

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, doctrine

i have two table in the database that user and Files that each user can have multilpe image so i used Collectiontype for adding multiple image create and read are working well but when i try to edit them i get this error [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A90Mu.png)

i looked every documention but i couldn't find anything to solve my problem 
here's what i have in usertype and Filestype 
https://gist.github.com/Bakhshi-Faisal/ffa62cc6b059f662243cf7e2564a03ef

Comment: Please add your code... Related entities, FormTypes, and so on... We can't provide help on a problem if we can't see where the problem might come from...

Comment: @Preciel i just upload all my files the problem is i can insert to the database but ican't edit or delete files thanks for helping me

Comment: Why did you reject the edit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change your form types accordingly:

```
class UserType extends AbstractType {

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('lastName')
        ->add('files',CollectionType::class, array(
              'entry_type' => AppBundle\Form\FilesType::class,
              'allow_add' => true,
              'allow_delete' => true,
        ));
...

class FilesType extends AbstractType {

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('file',FileType::class, array(
              'data_class' => null
        ));
...
```

Comment: it works but not completely i can edit it but when i add some change it can't save files in the database niether in the directiory . it means i can only update the name and last name can't update files i don't know where this problem come from

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "Data Transforms". Take a look at [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html)